# How to connect a few PCs without Internet access?

Tags: networking

I want to connect a few PCs in my company so that they can share files, chat, and transmit data. I have no Internet connection. I want to accomplish this without Internet but whenever needed I can connect them to the Internet, but for now there is no Internet service.

Please provide step-by-step instructions for proceeding as I am quite new to this sort of thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to establish a LAN if there is none so far. The hardware apart from PCs/laptops needed for this is switch and network cables mentioned in a previous answer That is only the infrastructure needed for any file sharing chat and other services. I assume you have Ubuntu as desktop laptop systems. Such systems needs to be connected over the LAN.

Samba is for sharing files to windows if you use.
- Native Linux utilities like telnet, ftp or more secure ones sftp, ssh will provide for data transfer between systems.
- Intranet webserver will help you if you need share common data to be accessible to others.
- Jabber can be used to setup chat.
- If you opt for internet service and need to share, squid as a proxy can help you.
Giving step by step instructions to be these is not possible here. 
So how you can go about it.

About LAN setup and TCP/IP setup - read any network basics book / article on internet.
TCP/IP on Ubuntu, you can get it from help.ubuntu.com
Ubuntu server manual describes, how to install and setup a server for hosting many of these services.

If you like specific help on anything post another question on those areas after mentioning your OS version as well.

Answer (score 1):

For sharing files you could use following guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/internet/C/networking-shares.html

For chat use a Jabber server:

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/jabberd2-server.html

Comment: Both of these URLs are 404-ing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) and several network cables.