# X does not start on boot

Tags: lightdm

After system upgrade to 13.10 there is no GUI at startup. I can login successfully and `startx` or `start lightdm`, but it should be done automatically.
I tried following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30278...-start-on-boot) and did:

- `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` (output: /usr/sbin/lightdm)
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
- `gedit /etc/init/lightdm.conf` and before command `exec lightdm` added `sleep 5`

Nothing seems to help the situation. How can I fix or debug this?

Comment: Appreciate it, Olli! How can I thank you?

Comment: Have you tried to purge lightdm and then reinstall it?